# i18n and JSON Schema?

Tags: jsonschema

Is there any formal means of internationalizing the `title` and `description` of a JSON schema? These properties are indicated by the [spec](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html) as being usable "to decorate a user interface", so their i18n becomes important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no means of doing so, but it is [part of a proposal](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/multilingual-meta-data-%28v5-proposal%29) for v5 of the spec.

Update: An active proposal is available at https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-vocabularies/issues/10